# Массовое вручение знаков за метки?

Tags: поддержка, метки

Заметил нечто странное в [ленте последних вручённых знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все знаки были вручены [буквально в один момент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/177/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2). В принципе, это нормально: знаки за метки пересчитываются и вручаются один раз в сутки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по [странице "лучшие участники"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2/topusers), все четверо давно заслужили этот знак давно, не вчера. Так что и вручение знака должно было произойти раньше.

Так что это было? Поправили какой-то баг?

Comment: Метки-то мусорные... Первая мысль была - кто-то начал их массово проставлять в старых вопросах. Но следов такой деятельности я не нашел.

Comment: Возможная причина: модератор слил накоторые метки в одну (напр, массивы, array -> массив). Это подтверждается тем, что, например, VladD дошёл разом до 217 в этой метке.

Comment: @Bookend синонимизация [tag:array] -> [tag:массив] была произведена ещё 7 апреля 2015 года. Отфильтруйте по слову "массив": http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms. А VladD дошёл далеко не разом, [за последний месяц у него всего +4](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2/topusers).

Comment: @PavelMayorov вот и я не нашёл. Вполне обычная [динамика текущих вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5b%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%5d%20is%3aq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как было указано в комментариях, причина данному поведению – объединение меток, проведенное вчера в районе шести вечера по Москве.

Когда кто–либо (в том числе модератор или сотрудник компании) назначают синоним к метке, в специальном разделе управления сайтом появляется предложение сделать объединение меток. Как раз вчера, увидев скопившуюся массу «предложений на объединение», понял, что пора бы отклонить или подтвердить объединения. После подтверждения происходит обновление подписок на вопросы, списков избранных меток, знаков и т. д.

Comment: То есть синонимы были назначены давно, а объединение произошло вчера, так?

Comment: Да! Совершенно верно.